# CheckedListBox memory leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

We're writing a diagnostic tool that needs to run for many hours at a time, but we're running into a mysterious Out of Memory Exception when we try to remove items from a CheckedListBox after the application has run for a couple of hours.

We initially tried using `checkedListBox.Items.Clear();`, and after some Googling around, we tried something like the following instead:

```
for (int i = checkedListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   checkedListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Unfortunately, the above did not solve the issue. I found that idea on the MSDN forums, but I can't for the life of me find the link again this morning. However, that forum did say that someone had profiled their application and found a memory leak in `CheckedListBox.Items.Clear()`.

Does anyone know of a functional work around?

**EDIT:** FingerTheCat's answer has *temporarily* solved our problem, so I will mark it as the answer for now. However, we've begun combing through the code to try and find the real problem. Unfortunately, the current implementation is largely spaghetti code, so it may be a few days before we find anything.

Comment: What kind of items are you adding to the checked list box? You may need to do some explicit cleanup of these objects in addition to just removing them from the list box (like calling `Dispose()` on them etc.).

Comment: You able to solve the memory leak with for loop?

Comment: You can safely assume that CheckedListBox does *not* have a memory leak.  Use Perfmon.exe to observe the .NET performance counters and check that regular garbage collections are taking place.  If not then you'll need to go out hunting for missing Dispose() calls in your app.

Comment: @Damith: No, unfortunately that didn't fix it. I'll edit the question to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: We're only adding strings to the `CheckedListBox`

Comment: Why do you think the list box is the problem? Maybe something else is consuming the memory.

Comment: send a snapshot from your application

Comment: Where do those strings come from? are the controls data bound? what else is running on the page? are there background threads? CheckedListBox has been a control in the .Net framework for over a decade. It is really unlikely that this is the culprit. It has been tested to death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, someone left a piece of debugging code in the application that was appending rather verbose log information to an `ArrayList` without ever clearing it. That code was also appending copies of the `ArrayList` to itself. Definitely not a good thing to forget to take out.

Answer (score -2):

The best thing to do, I think, is to call the GarbageCollector at some points in your code. Just add GC.Collect(); near some loops and it should fix your memory issue.

Comment: This is most certainly not the correct fix. GC.Collect() might still be useful while diagnosing the real problem.

Comment: Calling `GC.Collect()` is *not* the solution.